# How to send metrics to Prometheus by remote write in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prometheus

Recently I try to send metrics to Prometheus by remote write but I can't find any example in [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby) of prometheus-client and the closer answer is that using Prometheus::Client::Push but it seems like to go with pushgateway, so ... is anyone do it with ruby on rails before?

Running application(web) and Prometheus by docker compose code below

```
version: '3'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - /Users/jerryfang/pratice_rails/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - prometheus

networks:
  default:
    name: prom
```

and Prometheus of config below

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    scheme: http
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v2
    static_configs:
    - targets: []
scrape_configs:
  
- job_name: prom_test
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - web:3000

remote_write:
  - url: http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/write
```

add gem

```
gem "prometheus-client"
```

go into rails console

```
require 'prometheus/client/push'

registry = Prometheus::Client.registry
counter = Prometheus::Client::Counter.new(:my_counter, docstring: 'A counter of things')
registry.register(counter)

Prometheus::Client::Push.new(
  job: 'Jerry_test',
  gateway: 'https://prometheus:9090/api/v1/write',
).add(registry)
```

I got this error message `Prometheus::Client::Push::HttpClientError (status: 404, message: Not Found, body: 404 page not found)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this is against prometheus style. Promrtheus is a pull-based metrics collection system. You should consider exposing standard metrics page or using pushgateway for long-running jobs/tasks. The official guideline on how to choose [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).

That being said, most likely you haven't applied [reqiered](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#remote-write-receiver) ­`--web.enable-remote-write-receiver` flag to the Prometheus process.